# How to include java files in different directory? Cannot Find Symbol - Ant

Tags: java, ant

My main java file creates instances of classes in a different folder. How do I include them in Ant so that I can compile? As of right now, I am getting a 'Cannot Find Symbol Error'

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<project name="SeleniumProjectDataDriven" basedir="." default="compile">
    <target name="init">
        <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
        <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
        <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/class"/>
        <property name="lib.dir" value="../JAR"/>
        <property name="Common.dir" value="../Common"/>
        <property name="CommonBin.dir" value="${Common.dir}/src" />
    </target>

    <target name="prepare" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the code" depends="prepare">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${CommonBin.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.class" />
                </fileset> 

                <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                     <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here I am trying to receive the .class files in the ../Common/src folder.
However, it is not working. The second  works when the jars need to be included. However, not the .class files

Comment: Getting it from what?

Comment: Can you elaborate? If you are talking about the other class files, they are just in a different directory on the same computer.